# RandomForest in R - all factors have straight line in Partial plot

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to make a partial plot with package randomForest in R.
After I perform my random forest object I type

```
partialPlot(data.rforest, pred.data=act2, x.var=centroid, "C")
```

where `data.rforest` is my randomforest object, `act2` is the original dataset, `centroid` is one of the predictor and `C` is one of the classes in my response variable.
Whatever predictor or response class I try I always get a plot with a straight line. Similarly, If I set a categorical variable as predictor, I get a barplot with all the bar with the same height. 
I suppose I'm doing something wrong here because all other analysis on the same rforest object seem correct (e.g. `varImp` or `MDSplot`). Is it possible it is related to some option set in random forest object?

Comment: Without a working example, those of us who don't deal with this on daily basis will be hard to give you a hand. It would be helpful if you met us half way.

Comment: An example of how it works is the one given in the manual of the package: library(randomForest) data(iris) set.seed(543) iris.rf <- randomForest(Species~., iris) partialPlot(iris.rf, iris, Petal.Width, "versicolor")         Of course here it works. With my data this function doesn't work and I don't understand if is due to the randomForest object or to the function itself

Comment: You should whip up an example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Problem solved. I suppose it was a bug related to $ symbol, removing it and calling variables with "data=" in randomForest() it works... Thanks anyway